# Proof that eigenvectors corresponding to different eigenvalues are linearly independent.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If eigenvectors $x_1, x_2,...,x_k$ correspond to different eigenvalues $λ_1, λ_2,...,λ_k$, then $x_1, x_2,...,x_k$ are linearly independent.

**Proof:**

Suppose $$C_1{x_1}+C_2{x_2}+...C_k{x_k}=0 ...(1)$$ 
$$A(C_1{x_1}+C_2{x_2}+...C_k{x_k})=0$$
$$\Rightarrow C_1{λ_1}{x_1}+C_2{λ_2}{x_2}+...+C_k{λ_k}{x_k}=0...(2)$$
$$λ_k(1)-(2)=C_1{λ_1}{x_1}+C_2{λ_2}{x_2}+...+C_{k-1}{λ_k}{x_{k-1}}-C_1{λ_1}{x_1}-C_2{λ_2}{x_2}-...-C_{k-1}{λ_{k-1}}{x_{k-1}}=0$$
$$\Rightarrow C_1({λ_k}-{λ_1}){x_1}+...+C_{k-1}({λ_k}-{λ_{k-1}}){x_{k-1}}=0$$
And how to do next to show that $C_1=0=C_2=...=C_k$?

Comment: All the eigenvalues are different?

Comment: So we can never have that $\lambda_i -\lambda_j =0$

Comment: yes, they all are different.

Comment: @vadim123 it is not general

Comment: You should also conclude that eigenvectors are nonzero vectors by definition.

Comment: You can easily finish the argument by induction, start with a base case of two vectors. You sort of already have the inductive step! (hypothesis $x_1, x_2, \dots x_{k-1}$ linearly independent)

Comment: @WesleyStrik I see. I forgot some definition. Thanks a lot!